# Bevel vertices odd behavior

Tags: bevel

When I try to bevel a corner of my cube from a single selected vertex (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>), it does not flatten the corner like usual. Instead, I get a triangle that runs along *one* side of the cube... why?
However, when I create a new cube and do the same thing, it works as expected.

Comment: Maybe apply the scale of your object?

Comment: I decided to delete the object and start over. I'll try applying the scale next time.

Comment: Either the scale is not applied or you have some duplicate geometry somewhere.